# Python repeat set generator

Tags: python, iterator

Is there a simpler way of doing the following?

```
(set() for _ in itertools.repeat(None))
```

Note that it is different to `itertools.repeat(set())`, since the latter only constructs the set object once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
iter(set, None)
```

which calls the given callable until it returns `None` (what it won't).

Comment: Nice, didn't know that `iter` had a second form.